# How to read/update Local sqlite data when application is in suspend / background mode after every 30 min?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios5, background-process

How to read/update Local sqlite data when application is in suspend / background mode after every sec?
Below Is the Code what I am trying to Do
Right Now i just want to NsLog All the Id Present In local Sqlite Table After Every Second
But unable to do that.
Can any one tell me what i am doing wrong or can any one correct the following code. 
**Thanks In Advance**

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)app
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) { //Check if our iOS version supports multitasking I.E iOS 4
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) { //Check if device supports mulitasking
            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; //Get the shared application instance

            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task; //Create a task object

            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //Tell the system that we are done with the tasks
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Set the task to be invalid

                //System will be shutting down the app at any point in time now
            }];

            //Background tasks require you to use asyncrous tasks

            dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
            dispatch_source_t timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, backgroundQueue);
            dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0), 1*NSEC_PER_SEC, 0*NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource, ^{
                [self BackGroundTaskFunction];
            });
            dispatch_resume(timerSource);
        }
    }
}
-(void)BackGroundTaskFunction
{
   [self GetUserName]
    if (recordArray.count>0) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i<recordArray.count; i++) 
        {
            DB_data *db=(DB_data *)[recordArray objectAtIndex:i];
            Nslog(@"%d",db.Id);          
        }
    }
}
-(void)GetUserName{
    self.recordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    {
        const char *sql = "select * from UserName";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectStatement;

        int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectStatement, NULL);
        if(returnValue == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                [recordArray addObject:[[DB_data alloc] initwithDataSet:sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 0) UserName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)]]];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved My problem by using NSRUNLOOP which help me to make application keep running in background

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do that, only apps that play audio, are tracking user location or voip client are allowed to run in the background.

If your does not fall in one of those types of apps then you can not run in the background.

The code you post allows you to run a lengthy process for a maximum of 10 min.

Comment: Okay then tell how few app upload data on webserver from local sqlite in background mode?

Comment: They don't, they call the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` perform the upload, but if the task does not finish with in the 10min. they will have to wait until the user start the app again to try again. 10min. should be enough to update the data to a web service. If you want to pull data from a web service do thus when ever the app becomes available.  I don't see why you have to update the data every 30 min. since the data is only needed when the app becomes active or if the user changes data. You will only burn the battery and data plan of the user if keep updating.

Comment: well basically my job is check if any user change data on webserver it automatically download in local sqlite this is what my client requirement is

Comment: Then you will need to build a server to check this and use Push notification to alert the user that the data has changed. There is no way to do what you want with the SDK.

Comment: but he said it should automatically download without Any alert or etc

Comment: Then you will have to break the bad news to him that it is not possible.